# Right way to show div with ASP.NET server controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have hidden div with ASP.NET server buttons. I show a content of that div as modal window on the page via JavaScript by copying innerHTML, but buttons on that div don't fire server events. Who knows how to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code?  The minimal amount to reproduce the problem.  If the buttons are server control buttons and are tied to server-side click events then they _should_ work fine regardless of style changes made on the client in JavaScript, so I'm curious how you're achieving this result.

Answer (score 2):

A first guess would be that the innerHtml isn't a complete copy of the code needed to fire the events.

Maybe clone the node instead?

Comment: yes, I should use appendChild instead innerHTML. Everything works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't fire event on the server, but check all validators by ValidationGroup !? Something strang.

Comment: Could it be that when after copying the code you have two buttons with the same id? Asp.net doesn't like that, try to move the node instead of copying.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hidden div is inside the `<asp:Form></asp:Form>` tag block.

Answer (score 0):

there is much code.

Example is:

```
 <div id='divHidden' style='display:none'> <div id='divcontentToShow'>
 <!-- here is asp.net button -->
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
 </div> </div>
```

So, btnSubmit_Click event on the server doesn't fire when content of divcontentToShow copied to other div neither by appendChild nor innerHTML way.

Comment: Could you show us the surrounding code as well? As NerdFury says, it has to be inside the form-tag.